# About Laravel 4 Query Builder ,Range of variables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
$orderId = 1;

DB::table('users')
->whereIn("user_id",function($query)
{
   $query->select("user_id")->from('orders')->where('orders.id','>',$orderId);
})
->get();
```

i want to use the $orderId,but it's doesn't work,How should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo uneed to pass the `$orderId` into the closure - like this

```
$orderId = 1;

DB::table('users')
->whereIn("user_id",function($query) use ($orderId)
{
   $query->select("user_id")->from('orders')->where('orders.id','>',$orderId);
})
->get();
```

Comment: I think the keyword is **use** not uses

Comment: if i has more parameter,i need use like this "use($orderId,$moreParam)" ?